# ASP.Net Core authenticate with AAD and B2C

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have a web api written in ASP.Net Core 2.2 and we want to authenticate users against either an AAD or a B2C. This means we have some endpoints that can be accessed only by AAD users, others by B2C users and some by both.

In Startup.cs we have

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
   .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));

services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
   AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

Individually these work, but when we try to add the configuration for both at the same time, neither works.

I have also tried

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
   .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
   .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
```

But neither seems to work. How do we get this going?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I too faced similar problem and achieved by custom policy. Below is the Authentication code.

```
public static void AddAuthorization(this IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationRoot configuration)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer("AAD", options =>
            {
                options.MetadataAddress = configuration["AzureAd:Instance"] + configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"] +
                                          "/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration";
                options.Authority = configuration["AzureAd:Instance"] + configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];
                options.Audience = configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
                options.TokenValidationParameters =
                    new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidIssuer = $"https://sts.windows.net/{configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"]}/",
                    };
                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context => Task.CompletedTask,
                    OnChallenge = context => Task.CompletedTask,
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnAuthenticationFailed: " + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnTokenValidated = context =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Validated: " + context.SecurityToken);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            })
            .AddJwtBearer("B2C", options =>
        {
            options.Authority = configuration["AzureAdB2C:Instance"] + configuration["AzureAdB2C:Domain"] + "/" + configuration["AzureAdB2C:SignUpSignInPolicyId"] + "/v2.0";
            options.Audience = configuration["AzureAdB2C:ClientId"];

            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnMessageReceived = context => Task.CompletedTask,
                OnChallenge = context => Task.CompletedTask,
                OnAuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("OnAuthenticationFailed: " + context.Exception.Message);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
                OnTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Validated: " + context.SecurityToken);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        });
        services
            .AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AADUsers", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes("AAD")
                    .Build());

                options.AddPolicy("B2CUsers", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .AddAuthenticationSchemes("B2C")
                    .Build());
            });
    }
```

In the startup.cs add below code in ConfigureServices

```
services.AddAuthorization(Configuration);
```

Now in your controller you can decorate like this based on AD or B2CAD

```
[Authorize(Policy = "B2CUsers")] // For B2C authentication
[Authorize(Policy = "AADUsers")] // For AAD authentication
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do configuration for both like you're doing above.

You just need to configure B2C in the code and after that you need to use custom policies in Azure B2C. You need to define Azure AD as a claims provider that Azure B2C can communicate with through an endpoint. This will allow users to sign in by using Azure AD or social account.

Find detailed reference [here at Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom).

Comment: Unfortunately I am working with a heavily customised client provided B2C that we cannot change. Is there a way to achieve this in code?

Comment: Other option I could think of is register the app as Multi-tenant, which allows app to authenticate user from other AD which has permission. Ref: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect